# how to define bounded linear operator from $L^2+L^\infty\rightarrow L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request

how to define bounded linear operator from $L^2+L^\infty\rightarrow L^2$.
Or how to define the norm in the space $L^2+L^\infty$? Has anyone any reference to this topic?

where
$L^2+L^\infty=\{f|f=u+v,u\in L^2,v\in L^\infty\}$

Comment: I am not familiar with your notation.  How do you define $L^2 + L^{\infty}$?

Comment: @XanderHenderson functions which are the sum of a function in $L^2$ and a function in $L^\infty$

Comment: I guess that you can use the weaker norm, or the maximum of both (if I remember correctly the maximum of two norms is a norm)

Comment: @Masacroso or the norm $$K_t(x) = \inf_{a+b=x} ( \lVert a\rVert_2+t \lVert b\rVert_\infty)$$ for any given parameter $t>0$. (Keyword: "K-functional")

Comment: Are these $L^2$ and $L^{\infty}$ spaces of finite or infinite measure?

Comment: @clark I am more interested in unbounded measure

Comment: @ClementC. That is it. K-functional, thanks for your keywords, I can do the rest then.

Comment: You're welcome!